# Extracting plain text from HTML file depending on conditions set within the file to target Excel using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, excel, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to export data from locally saved HTML user manuals to target excel files.

I'm very new to python, so far I have only been able to load the HTML file and test it is actually being read. for instance, running this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(r"C:\localfile"), "html.parser")
for tag in soup.find_all(re.compile("^b")):
    print(tag.name)
```

I have 12 HTML files with hundreds of commands each.

Each command page specifies the permissions it requires, and all commands are shown as (COMMANDNAME)

[Command example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9xzj.jpg)

the target excels look somewhat like this:

[Source excel file 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdLfK.jpg)

[Source excel file 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHhEd.jpg)

So, I'd need to export the command names one time per each type of permission it has. One per column.

In this example, the output I'd need would be

DSP DBCLUSTER   DSP DBCLUSTER    DSP DBCLUSTER

on both files, since both fulfill the first 3 permissions.
Sometimes commands have only 1 type of one permission and 3 of the other, etc.

I'm struggling to find a conditional statement to do this.

Thanks a lot!

Edit:

Here's a snippet of the source HTML code

```
</div>
<div class="articleBox">
<h1 class="topicTitle-h1">8.1.5.1.1.1 Display CSDB Cluster Information (DSP DBCLUSTER)</h1>
<ul><li><a href="#EN-US_CONCEPT_0129626985__1.3.1.1">Function</a></li><li><a href="#EN-US_CONCEPT_0129626985__1.3.2.1">Note</a></li><li><a href="#EN-US_CONCEPT_0129626985__1.3.3.1">Local User Rights</a></li><li><a href="#EN-US_CONCEPT_0129626985__1.3.4.1">EMS User Rights</a></li><li><a href="#EN-US_CONCEPT_0129626985__1.3.5.1">Parameters</a></li><li><a href="#EN-US_CONCEPT_0129626985__1.3.6.1">Example</a></li><li><a href="#EN-US_CONCEPT_0129626985__1.3.7.1">Output Description</a></li></ul><div><div class="section"><h4 class="sectiontitle"><a name="EN-US_CONCEPT_0129626985__1.3.1.1"></a><a name="1.3.1.1"></a><a href="#EN-US_CONCEPT_0129626985" class="sectiontitle2contents">Function</a></h4><p>This command is used to query the CSDB cluster information.</p>
</div>
<div class="section"><h4 class="sectiontitle"><a name="EN-US_CONCEPT_0129626985__1.3.2.1"></a><a name="1.3.2.1"></a><a href="#EN-US_CONCEPT_0129626985" class="sectiontitle2contents">Note</a></h4><p>None</p>
</div>
<div class="section"><h4 class="sectiontitle"><a name="EN-US_CONCEPT_0129626985__1.3.3.1"></a><a name="1.3.3.1"></a><a href="#EN-US_CONCEPT_0129626985" class="sectiontitle2contents"

> Local User Rights</a></h4> manage-ug; system-ug; monitor-ug

</div>
<div class="section"><h4 class="sectiontitle"><a name="EN-US_CONCEPT_0129626985__1.3.4.1"></a><a name="1.3.4.1"></a><a href="#EN-US_CONCEPT_0129626985" class="sectiontitle2contents"
> EMS User Rights</a></h4>G_1: 
> administrator-level command group; G_2: operator-level command group;
> G_3: user-level command group
```

The relevant strings that determine how many times the command must be repeated are shown after the > (Local User Rights and EMS User rights)

The expected output would be what I posted above,
the name of the command repeated x times and respecting the order of the columns
If only the first column is used, then in this case the output would be

DSP DBCLUSTER, (DSP DBCLUSTER),(DSP DBCLUSTER),(DSP DBCLUSTER)

If only the first and 3rd columns were used, then the output would be

DSP DBCLUSTER,(DSP DBCLUSTER),DSP DBCLUSTER, (DSP DBCLUSTER)

A missing permission would result in the command being put in parenthesis

Comment: Could you add a minimal reproducible example, consisting of a part of the the html code and what the expected output is.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. HTML and output added.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following script should help you. It reads the HTML you have provided (from a saved file) and searches for `<div>` elements with `class='section'`. For each section it attempts to locate matching rights and then builds a suitable row for your two output CSV files:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

not_used = ["(DSP DBCLUSTER)"] * 4
used = "DSP DBCLUSTER"

data_g = []
data_ug = []

header_g = ["No.", "G_1 Administrator", "G_2 Operator", "G_3 User", "G_4 Guest"]
header_ug = ["No.", "Manage-Ug", "System-Ug", "Monitor-Ug", "Visit-Ug"]

data_g = ["G_1", "G_2", "G_3", "G_4"]
data_ug = ["manage", "system", "monitor", "visit"]

count_g = 1
count_ug = 1

with open('test.html') as f_html:
    html = f_html.read()
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

with open('g.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_g, open('ug.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_ug:
    csv_g = csv.writer(f_g)
    csv_g.writerow(header_g)
    
    csv_ug = csv.writer(f_ug)
    csv_ug.writerow(header_ug)

    for section in soup.find_all('div', class_='section'):
        row = not_used[:]
        text = section.h4.next_sibling.strip()
    
        if '-ug' in text:
            for index, parm in enumerate(data_ug):
                if parm in text:
                    row[index] = used
            csv_ug.writerow([count_ug] + row)
            count_ug += 1
            #print(text, row)
            
        elif 'G_' in text:
            for index, parm in enumerate(data_g):
                if parm in text:
                    row[index] = used
            csv_g.writerow([count_g] + row)
            count_g += 1
            #print(text, row)
```

For your HTML, there is only one section per type, as such the output CSV files would appear as follows:

**g.csv**

```
No.,G_1 Administrator,G_2 Operator,G_3 User,G_4 Guest
1,DSP DBCLUSTER,DSP DBCLUSTER,DSP DBCLUSTER,(DSP DBCLUSTER)
```

**ug.csv**

```
No.,Manage-Ug,System-Ug,Monitor-Ug,Visit-Ug
1,DSP DBCLUSTER,DSP DBCLUSTER,DSP DBCLUSTER,(DSP DBCLUSTER)
```

Not having the actual full HTML makes it difficult to test.